# Rails FactoryGirl defining syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

While using factory girl gem, we create a factories.rb file with the syntax as

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    ...  
  end
  ...
end
```

So what exactly does FactoryGirl.define syntax means ?
Is it similar to

```
class FactoryGirl
  def factory :model do
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

FactoryGirl, like many Ruby gems, defines a "domain specific language" or DSL for the purpose of simplifying configuration. This is a common pattern.

Your example looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    ...  
  end
  ...
end
```

What's happening is the `factory` method is being called with the argument `:model` which is additionally passed a block. As always, the method in question is free to decide what to do with the block. In this case it is saved and executed later during the factory generation process.

Your re-interpretation of it doesn't make any sense as that's not valid Ruby. You cannot have a symbol as an argument specifier. Remember that `factory` is a pre-existing method, not one you're defining at that point.

If this is all a bit hazy you'll need to experiment with blocks more to see how they work within Ruby. They're used for a number of things so you need to understand how each sets expectations on what the block can do, what it should return, and how many times it will be called, if at all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will look into the DSL defined for FactoryGirl. Thanks again !!

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, anything with `do end` is a block and all blocks are attached to a method.

So in your example, `FactoryGirl.define` is a method call with a block as a parameter. `factory :model` is also a method call with a block as a parameter, but in this case the `:model` is also a parameter passed in.

You can think of the methods being defined in FactoryGirl **conceptually** like this:

```
class FactoryGirl
  def self.define
    yield # do something w/ the block passed in
    ...
  end

  def factory(model_name, &block)
    block.call # do something w/ the block passed in
    ...
  end
end
```